# Stream Airfare data

Tags: data-request, transportation

Where would be the best place to find up the the minute data on airline ticket prices, IE at the moment cost of a flight from Hamburg to Toronto.

I know sites like skyscanner.com and Kayak.com have this kind of data. Do they buy it from airlines? Or is there another way to get this data live?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Airlines distribute fare information through something called a [global distribution system (GDS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Distribution_System). An example of one such system is [SABRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabre_%28computer_system%29). There are lots of different kinds of GDSs out there, and you can find them with a simple internet search. The [International Air Transport Association (IATA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association) is probably your best resource for finding out more about GDS and trends there.